# Find an explicit formula for a sequence (plus proof)

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I examine the Proth numbers.
A number $n$ is called a Proth number, iff it is of the form
$n = h\cdot 2^k+1$ for an integer $k\geq 1$ and an odd integer $h<2^k$.
Now we order these numbers, primarily by their exponent, starting at $k=1$.
And secondarily by the coefficient $h$, starting at $1$ and ending at $h = 2^k-1$.
Then we get the sequence
$$
(a_n) 
= (1\cdot 2^1+1, 1\cdot 2^2+1, 3\cdot 2^2+1, 1\cdot 2^3+1,\dots)
= (3, 5, 13, 9,\dots).
$$
Now I want to calculate the $i-$ th number $a(i)$ and prove the formula.
Let's have a look at this table (exponent $k$ downwards, $h$ to the side):

|  | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a(1) |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | a(2) | a(3) |  |  |  |
| 3 | a(4) | a(5) | a(6) | a(7) |  |
| 4 | a(8) | a(9) | a(10) | a(11) | a(12) |

For every fixed $k$, there are exactly $2^{k-1}$ Proth numbers.
So the amount of all Proth numbers with exponent $\leq k$ is
$2^0+2^1+2^2+\dots+2^{k-1} = 2^k-1$.
It follows that $a(2^k)$ is the first Proth number with the exponent $k+1$, so $a(2^k) = 1\cdot 2^{k+1}+1$.

Now comes my problem.
I know how to proof the rest, but I want it to be formally correct.
The idea is that if we move one to the side, we get the next odd number as coefficient.
Hence: $a(2^k+c) = (2c+1)\cdot 2^{k+1}+1.$

But how can I get a formally correct proof?